# insert into where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

```
INSERT INTO LOOPT2 (TOKEN_STATUS) 
      VALUES (1) where Token_NO = :Token_No;
```

I Know this will not work with where claus  its a detailed block please help me what i did is this but not worked for me please help me

```
DECLARE 
  TOKEN_NO NUMBER;
  TOKEN_STATUS1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  GO_BLOCK('TOKEN_REC2');
  FIRST_RECORD; 

 LOOP
  BEGIN
     SELECT SR_NO, TOKEN_STATUS 
       INTO TOKEN_NO, TOKEN_STATUS1 
       FROM LOOPT2 
      WHERE TOKEN_STATUS = :TOKEN_NO 
        AND V_ID=1;

   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO LOOPT2 (TOKEN_STATUS) 
      VALUES (1);
  END;

    EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
    NEXT_RECORD;
 END LOOP;  

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: IS THERE ANY ONE WHO CAN ANSWER THIS :(

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem. Your question is too vague. You want to update the column `TOKEN_STATUS` where the token_no is available, and INSERT if it is not?

Comment: thanks barbaros i have a table loopt2 which have column sr_no which is equal to TOKEN_NO, it has data inside as i will type in forms detail block and token status dont have any data i want to update just that column as 1 when i commit form and changes token status as 1where sr_no =:token_no

Comment: `UPDATE LOOPT2 SET TOKEN_STATUS=1
WHERE SR_NO = :TOKEN_NO` is all you want? No PL/SQL may be ?

Comment: dear @MaheswaranRavisankar i did this but not worked for me `UPDATE LOOPT2 SET LOOPT2.TOKEN_STATUS=1 WHERE LOOPT2.SR_NO = :TOKEN_REC2.TOKEN_NO;
COMMIT;`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar dear you are exect what i want but that not worked its detailed block not a single row

Comment: adding `and v_id = 1` in `WHERE` clause will help?

Comment: bundle of thanks @MaheswaranRavisankar and @barbaros its done with pre insert and `UPDATE LOOPT2 SET LOOPT2.TOKEN_STATUS=1 WHERE LOOPT2.SR_NO = :TOKEN_REC2.TOKEN_NO;` Again lot of thanks for both of you God Bless you all of you lot of happiness in your lifes

Comment: you're welcome. God bless you, too ..

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need an `if` statement such as :

```
..
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   IF ( TOKEN_NO = :TOKEN_NO ) THEN
    INSERT INTO LOOPT2 (TOKEN_STATUS) 
      VALUES (1);
   END IF;
  END;
..
```

or [`dual`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=40913fb7a73329084d4e1c6aaaf09aea) table :

```
..
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO LOOPT2 (TOKEN_STATUS) 
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE TOKEN_NO = :TOKEN_NO;
  END;
..
```

Comment: thanks barbaros I tried both unfortunately not worked for me any suggestion one thing is that NO_DATA_FOUND but i have data same in SR_NO but not in Token_status is there any thing worked for me sql%found i tried but when compile it provide me error

Comment: you're welcome @user2943102 . Are you sure about `TOKEN_NO=:TOKEN_NO` collation or should that be `TOKEN_STATUS1 = :TOKEN_NO` ? Btw, take `Commit` before `End`.

Comment: ohh you are right where clause is `token_no=:token_no` not token status i changed but not worked